# How to get tag of clicked UIButton Without IB?

Tags: iphone, tags, uibutton

Can anyone tell me that How to get tag of a UIButton when i click on it...

I have made 5 buttons having tag 1,2,3,4 & 5 resp.(all are calling same method getTag )

and i tried following ways for that method

**- Methgod-1**

-(void)getTag{
            //I know that this will never work
}

**- Methgod-2**

-(void)getTag:(id)sender{
            //Unable to access sender.tag property
}

**- Methgod-3**

-(void)getTag:(UIButton*)sender{
            //Program crashes
}

I am not using IB  please help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both method-2 and -3 can be correct - in method 2 you only need to cast sender to UIButton explicitly, e.g:

```
-(void)getTag:(id)sender{ 
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    switch (btn.tag){
     ...
    } 
}
```

Possible reason why method 1 works and 2and 3 not is wrong selector you assign to your button action. For method 1 it should be

```
@selector(getTag)
```

For second

```
@selector(getTag:); // NOte ':' in selector which denotes that method gets 1 parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method 2 and code as follows,

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;



button.tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton * myB = [[UIButton alloc]init];

myB.tag = 2;

NSLog(@"TAG=%i",myB.tag);

//OUTPUT: 'TAG=2'
```

Comment: Sorry, i thought it was intuitive enough that the sender id of the event is the button object..